# Merging "upstream updates" when files were renamed and moved locally?

Tags: git, version-control

I've acquired lots of "media files", and I'm looking for a way to manage them, such that pulling updates of the original files works "seamlessly". I'll try to explain with an example.

Let's assume I bought a bunch of "cat pictures and videos" bundles (distributed as zip files) from all over the internet. They all have different directory structures and naming conventions, but that just won't do for my "cat library app", so I commit those files to git (for example) and then move and rename them into one single "logical" directory structure, and commit those changes too.

Now, by the time I'm done coding my "cat library app", quite a few of the files in those bundles were updated, say with higher resolution, or additional Photoshoping, ... So, I'd like to apply those changes to my files, but the name and locations don't match anymore.

So, how do I do that (with git, or something else)?

Comment: For version control binary files, you'd better manage then by git-lfs. 
And git won't recognize the updated/renamed pictures and vidoes since the files in upstream are not managed into git repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Partially rewritten; what I stated in my original answer was true, but I was implicitly drawing a conclusion that was not right (because I misapplied how the similarity metric is used when thinking about the merge).

My recommendation as far as how best to handle it is unchanged, though.

---

I'd say you're not exactly working in git's "sweet spot".  I don't have a recommendation for a different tool, and in any event tool recommendations would be off-topic for SO.  And I'm not saying you *can't* use git, but here's what you're up against:

1) You're tracking potentially-large binary files, which is not git's forte.

2) You want to track through renames.  In git a rename is not directly tracked, but is reconstructed from deletes and adds using a similarity metric.  So you're constantly going to rely on git resolving "conflicts" of the sort "ours 'moved' a file and theirs edited the file".  This isn't always git's strongest suit, especially if there are a lot of files being moved around.

The first issue you can mitigate using a tool like git LFS.

I'd originally noted that many of your updates would have low - possibly 0% - similarity metrics.  That's true, but you can work around it as long as you always update in one commit, and move in a separate commit.

So, you *could* handle it simply by keeping an "upstream" branch with the original file structure, always applying the updates first to that branch without moving the files, and then merging that branch to your master (where you did the initial renames).  As long as no files are duplicates, git should be able to work out that the previous merge "moves" the files to new locations, and reconcile that with the changes as it generates the subsequent merge.  But it may be slow for a large set of files all being moved, and may require you to tweak config settings that limit the number of renames git will try to resolve (see `diff.renameLimit`).

But to avoid the potential issues with rename detection, instead you might want to do this:

1) Keep the files in your repo at their original locations (possibly using LFS or similar)

2) Script the process of moving them into your unified directory structure, and source control the script (analogous to a source-controlled automated build script for a more typical software project)

Comment: Your answer is useful, but by coding manually the moves/renames in a file, I introduce the potential for "human error", so I'll wait a day or two, in case there is an alternative solution.

Comment: @SebastienDiot - That's an odd way to look at it.  "Coding manually" is a contradiction.  You can automate the moves by coding them, so that then once you've tested your code you've removed the potential for further human error; or you can move them manually and risk getting it wrong every time.  But hey, if you need an excuse to wait for an answer you like better, who am I to argue?  Best of luck.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear; all those files are managed in a "specialised editor"; I have to move them in the editor so that references to the files in other files are automatically updated (really hard to do manually). So, in effect I have to move them in the IDE first, and then remember what I moved, and type that in some "batch file". So I'm basically doing it twice, and that introduces the chance for divergence.

Comment: I've just checked my "source" folder; we're talking about 690 bundles/220K files/21K folders/470GB. Imagine you had to type "only" 21K move commands in a file manually? There must be a better way.